# Update Pyplot Subplots with Images in a Loop

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I think I'm doing something really dumb, but I can't quite figure it out.  I want to create a class to display  a set of images as subplots; the display should be updated manually from within a loop.  Here's the class I've created to try to do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class tensor_plot:
    def __init__(self, tensor_shape, nrows=1):
        self.img_height, self.img_width, self.num_imgs = tensor_shape
        self.nrows = nrows
        self.ncols = self.num_imgs // nrows
        assert(self.ncols*self.nrows == self.num_imgs)
        self.fig, self.a = plt.subplots(self.nrows, self.ncols, sharex='col', sharey='row')
        for (row, col) in zip(range(self.nrows), range(self.ncols)):
            self.a[row, col] = plt.imshow(np.zeros([self.img_height, self.img_width]))

    def update(self, tensor):
        n=0
        for row in range(self.nrows):
            for col in range(self.ncols):
                self.a[row,col].set_data(tensor[:,:,n].squeeze())
                n += 1
        plt.show()
```

When I try to pass a tensor in to update, it says no `set_data` attribute.  But using `dir` there is such an attribute.

```
In [322]: tp = tensor_plot(l10.shape, 4)

In [323]: tp.update(l10)
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_data'


In [324]: dir(tp.a[0,0])
Out[324]: 
['_A',
...
 'set_data',
...
 'update_from',
 'write_png',
 'zorder']
```

If I add  a line `print(dir(self.a[row,col]))` in the loop, it is true that `set_data` isn't there though!  Same comment applies to `imshow`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Initially `self.a` is an array of subplots. Later you assign images to the diagonal of that array. It has then some subplots and some images in it and for sure this calls for trouble. Make sure to use different arrays for different objects!!

Comment: Thanks -- that makes sense!  So I'm thinking I can just leave the final for loop out of the constructor.  What is the proper  way to make a particular  subplot  display an image defined in a tensor?

Comment: O.k. -- I think if i just use `self.a[row,col].imshow` in the update method  I'll be good.  Thanks again!

Comment: Well, that creates a new image per update (which is fine if you only have 2 or 3 updates or so), but would be massively inefficient if updating occurs more often. `.set_data` should be fine, just use a different array, like `self.b` for the images.

Answer (score 0):

With many thanks to @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest, here's the final code that works for me (in case it's  useful to others).

```
class tensor_plot:
    def __init__(self, tensor_shape, nrows=1):
        self.img_height, self.img_width, self.num_imgs = tensor_shape
        self.nrows = nrows
        self.ncols = self.num_imgs // nrows
        assert(self.ncols*self.nrows == self.num_imgs)
        self.fig, self.a = plt.subplots(self.nrows, self.ncols, sharex='col', sharey='row')

        self.imgs = np.array( [   [ self.a[row, col].imshow(np.zeros([self.img_height, self.img_width])) for col in range(self.ncols)    ] for row in range(self.nrows)])
        plt.pause(0.1)


    def update(self, tensor):
        n=0
        for row in range(self.nrows):
            for col in range(self.ncols):
                self.imgs[row,col].set_data(tensor[:,:,n].squeeze())
                self.imgs[row,col].set_clim(vmin=0, vmax=255)
                n += 1
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        plt.pause(0.01)
        plt.draw_all()
```